# Как правильно настроить редирект по refferer?

Tags: nginx

Что сделал я. 1. добавил в nginix.conf в http карту хостов

```
map $http_host $invalid_referer {
hostnames;

default                           0;

    # Put regexes for undesired referers here
    "~social-buttons.com"             1;
    "~semalt.com"                     1;
    "~kambasoft.com"                  1;
    "~savetubevideo.com"              1;
    "~descargar-musica-gratis.net"    1;
    "~7makemoneyonline.com"           1;
    "~baixar-musicas-gratis.com"      1;
    "~iloveitaly.com"                 1;
    "~ilovevitaly.ru"                 1;
    "~fbdownloader.com"               1;
    "~econom.co"                      1;
    "~buttons-for-website.com"        1;
    "~buttons-for-your-website.com"   1;
    "~srecorder.co"                   1;
    "~darodar.com"                    1;
    "~priceg.com"                     1;
    "~blackhatworth.com"              1;
    "~adviceforum.info"               1;
    "~hulfingtonpost.com"             1;
    "~best-seo-solution.com"          1;
    "~googlsucks.com"                 1;
    "~theguardlan.com"                1;
    "~i-x.wiki"                       1;
    "~buy-cheap-online.info"          1;
    "~Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com"       1;
    "~altera-auto.ru"       1;
    "~auto-kay.ru"       1;
}
```

Добавил в сервер проверку.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.hack-it-up.ru;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 444;
    }

    root /var/www/hack-it-up.ru/public;
    index /../bin/www;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://134.0.112.216:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Ничего не работает. Может я что-то не так понял или что-то не так подключил?

Comment: А при чём тут `$http_host`?

Comment: Вообще читать сюда http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers

Comment: Ну я вроде по-человечески написал, что гуглю с 8 утра... причём тут "читать сюда", когда я попросил показать на примере, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Лучше всё-таки хотя бы примерно понимать что вы делаете.

Comment: Я уже кажется врубился.  Вопрос у меня такой. Ко мне на сайт идут запросы с двух доменов по реферу их вижу с altera-auto.ru auto-kay.ru . Как их перекинуть на ответ 444? какая это должна быть директива? или как настроить $invalid_referer ? смысл описанного в документации я вроде уже понял. в valid_referers задаются те реферы, что считаются верными. А как закрыть для конкретных реферов?

Comment: кажется решил вопрос сделав `if ($http_referer ~* (altera-auto.ru|auto-kay.ru|m.avito.ru) ) {
        return   444;
    }` Понаблюдаю ещё. Если плохих новостей не будет, значит я всё верно сделал.